# ativando o phpmyadmin

Tags: linux, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, xampp

Estou rodando o XAMPP, porém o meu phpmyadmin está desabilitado já fiz de tudo para ativar, existe alguma outra opção, segue abaixo o erro.

> #2002 - Arquivo ou diretorio nao encontrado
>
> O servidor não está respondendo (ou o soquete do servidor local não
>   está configurado corretamente)

Comment: Qual o sistema operacional onde o xaampp está instalado?

Comment: ubuntu (linux).

Answer (score 3):

Tente fazer o seguinte, parar todos os serviços e inicializar novamente, utilize os comandos abaixo para parar os serviços

```
sudo opt/lampp/lampp stop              
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop    
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

OU

```
sudo service apache2 stop
sudo service mysql stop
```

Depois de parar os serviços, inicie novamente

```
sudo opt/lampp/lampp start
```

Tente novamente abrir o phpmyadmin novamente

**Traduzido de: [stackoverflow EN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426501/how-to-solve-the-xampp-1-7-7-phpmyadmin-mysql-error-2002-in-ubuntu)**

Comment: cara está dando o mesmo erro, o estranho é que quando dou o comando 'service mysql stop' no terminal, ele me fala que o trabalho é desconhecido???

Comment: @user3677610 Parece que o mysql não foi instalado corretamente, digite `sudo service mysql status`, a saída deve ser algo como `mysql start/running, process 835`, se ocorrer o mesmo erro tente reinstalar o programa

Comment: da na mesma, a hora que esta instalando o mysql no terminal ele trava no meio do caminho

Comment: Talvez esteja conflitando com alguma versão do mysql já instalado, tente desinstalar o mysql, `sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server`, veja se este link ajuda http://tipslegais10.blogspot.com/2013/01/desinstalar-mysql-no-linux-por-completo.html

Comment: bom dia nao consegui resolver o problema ainda, ja removi o mysql da minha pasta do computador, mas ele nao esta ativando, e chega a confirmar na hora qe sobe o servidor, mas no status do xampp aparece desabilitado..

Comment: consegui resolver era fato estava rodando dois apache bastou eu dar um service apache2 stop e resolvi, muito obrigado

Answer (score -2):

Como tirar erros do Mysql e viver em paz! :)

1- se você acessar o mysql pelo terminal e o erro for referente a falta de existencia de um diretório, então poderá ser que você tenha que instalar o mysql-server, assim:
    sudo apt-get install mysql-server

2- se você tentar entrar no mysql pelo phpmyadmin e der o seguinte erro: phpmyadmin ERROR - #2002, ou algo do tipo, poderá ser que você tem dois mysql instalados e rodando ao mesmo tempo, o que gera conflitos. Para resolver isso basta encerrar o mysql e deixar apenas o do xampp rodando, assim:
    cd /etc/init.d
    # ./mysql stop
    # ./apache stop
-Após isso, basta startar o mysql dentro do lampp, assim:
    -dentro da pasta /opt:
        opt/lampp/lampp start , ou , sudo opt/lampp/lampp
    -ou dentro da pasta lampp, assim:
        sudo ./lampp start

3- se para você aparece um erro do tipo: Existing configuration file (config.inc.php) is not readable…, significa que você deu uma permissão de alteração do arquivo ou execução, sendo que esse arquivo é apenas para leitura, e o mysql não inicia se você não mudar a permissão, dessa forma basta digitar:
    -procure o arquivo, no meu caso ficou assim:
        cd opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/
    -dentro do diretório /phpmyadmin, possui o arquivo config.inc.php, então dentro do diretório, digite:
    sudo chmod 700 config.inc.php
-Dessa forma o arquivo poderá ser executado pelo mysql sem nenhuma interrupção.